JpaRepository Whitelabel Error Page - This application has no explicit mapping for /error
I am trying to extend my implementation by adding a second repository (Review).  However, when I try to access http://localhost:8080/api/reviews I get the above error.  Can anyone spot where I've messed up?  I'm really knew to this so no doubt I've made a rookie mistake.
Folder structure
ProductController:
package gerry.stockcontrol.controller;

import gerry.stockcontrol.exception.ProductNotFoundException;
import gerry.stockcontrol.model.Product;
import gerry.stockcontrol.service.ProductServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/products")

//http://localhost:8080/api/products
public class ProductController {

    public ProductController(ProductServiceImpl productServiceImpl) {
        this.productServiceImpl = productServiceImpl;
    }

    @Autowired
    private final ProductServiceImpl productServiceImpl;

    @GetMapping("/searchname")
    public List<Product> searchProductsByName(@RequestParam(value="name") String name){
        return productServiceImpl.findByName(name);
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchdescription")
    public List<Product> searchProductsByDescription(@RequestParam(value="description") String description){
        return productServiceImpl.findByDescription(description);
    }

    @GetMapping
    public List<Product> getAllProducts(){
        return productServiceImpl.getAllProducts();
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Product getProductById(@PathVariable Long id) throws ProductNotFoundException {
        return productServiceImpl.getProductById(id);
    }

    @GetMapping("/searchstocklevel")
    public List<Product> searchProductsByStockLevel(@RequestParam(value="stocklevel") int stocklevel){
        return productServiceImpl.findByStockLevel(stocklevel);
    }

    @PostMapping
    public Product createProduct(@RequestBody Product product){
        return productServiceImpl.createProduct(product);
    }

    @PutMapping("/{id}")
    public Product updateProduct(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody Product product) throws ProductNotFoundException{
        return productServiceImpl.updateProduct(id, product);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("{id}")
    public void deleteProduct(@PathVariable Long id) throws ProductNotFoundException
    {
        productServiceImpl.deleteProduct(id);
    }

}


ReviewController:
package gerry.stockcontrol.controller;

import gerry.stockcontrol.exception.ReviewNotFoundException;
import gerry.stockcontrol.model.Review;
import gerry.stockcontrol.service.ReviewServiceImpl;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;

@CrossOrigin(origins = "*", allowedHeaders = "*")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/reviews")

//http://localhost:8080/api/reviews
public class ReviewController {

    public ReviewController(ReviewServiceImpl reviewServiceImpl) {
        this.reviewServiceImpl = reviewServiceImpl;
    }

    @Autowired
    private final ReviewServiceImpl reviewServiceImpl;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Review> getAllReviews(){
        return reviewServiceImpl.getAllReviews();
    }


    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Review getReviewById(@PathVariable Long id) throws ReviewNotFoundException {
        return reviewServiceImpl.getReviewById(id);

    }
}


Product Model:
package gerry.stockcontrol.model;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Double price;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer stock;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Review> reviews;

    //Getters and Setters

    public Long getID(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name){
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription(){
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description){
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Double getPrice(){
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Double price){
        this.price = price;
    }

    public Integer getStock(){
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(Integer stock){
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Product{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", description='" + description + '\'' +
                ", price='" + price + '\'' +
                ", stock='" + stock + '\'' +
                ", reviews='" + reviews + '\'' +
                '}';
    }



}


Review Model:
package gerry.stockcontrol.model;


import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "reviews")
public class Review {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private Integer rating;

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String comment;

    @ManyToOne
    private Product product;



    public Review(Product product, int rating, String comment) {
        this.rating = rating;
        this.comment = comment;
        this.product = product;
    }

    public int getRating() {
        return rating;
    }

    public void setRating(int rating) {
        this.rating = rating;
    }

    public String getComment() {
        return comment;
    }

    public void setComment(String comment) {
        this.comment = comment;
    }


@Override
public String toString()
{
    return "Review{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", rating='" + rating + '\'' +
            ", comment='" + comment + '\'' +
            '}';
}

}



ProductRepository:
package gerry.stockcontrol.repository;

import gerry.stockcontrol.model.Product;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import java.util.List;

public interface ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<Product, Long> {
     List<Product>findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(String name);
     List<Product>findByDescriptionContainingIgnoreCase(String description);
     List<Product>findByStockGreaterThanEqual(int stockLevel);
}


ReviewRepository:
package gerry.stockcontrol.repository;

import gerry.stockcontrol.model.Review;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import java.util.List;

public interface ReviewRepository extends JpaRepository<Review, Long> {
     List<Review>findByProductId(Long productId);
}


ProductServiceImpl:
package gerry.stockcontrol.service;

import gerry.stockcontrol.exception.ProductNotFoundException;
import gerry.stockcontrol.model.Product;
import gerry.stockcontrol.repository.ProductRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ProductServiceImpl {
    private final ProductRepository productRepository;

    public ProductServiceImpl(ProductRepository productRepository) {
        this.productRepository = productRepository;
    }

    public List<Product> getAllProducts() {
        return productRepository.findAll();
    }

    public Product getProductById(Long id) throws ProductNotFoundException{
        return productRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ProductNotFoundException("Product not found with id: " + id));
    }

    public Product createProduct(Product product){
        return productRepository.save(product);
    }

    public Product updateProduct(Long id, Product product) throws ProductNotFoundException{
        Product existingProduct = getProductById(id);
        existingProduct.setName(product.getName());
        existingProduct.setDescription(product.getDescription());
        existingProduct.setPrice(product.getPrice());
        existingProduct.setStock(product.getStock());
        return productRepository.save(existingProduct);
    }

    public void deleteProduct(Long id) throws ProductNotFoundException{
        getProductById(id);
        productRepository.deleteById(id);
    }

    public List<Product> findByName(String name){
        return productRepository.findByNameContainingIgnoreCase(name);
    }

    public List<Product> findByDescription(String description){
        return productRepository.findByDescriptionContainingIgnoreCase(description);
    }

    public List<Product> findByStockLevel(int stockLevel){
        return productRepository.findByStockGreaterThanEqual(stockLevel);
    }

}


ReviewServiceImpl:
package gerry.stockcontrol.service;

import gerry.stockcontrol.exception.ProductNotFoundException;
import gerry.stockcontrol.exception.ReviewNotFoundException;
import gerry.stockcontrol.model.Product;
import gerry.stockcontrol.model.Review;
import gerry.stockcontrol.repository.ReviewRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import java.util.List;

@Service
public class ReviewServiceImpl {
    private final ReviewRepository reviewRepository;

    public ReviewServiceImpl(ReviewRepository reviewRepository) {
        this.reviewRepository = reviewRepository;
    }

    public List<Review> getAllReviews() {
        return reviewRepository.findAll();
    }


    public Review getReviewById(Long id) throws ReviewNotFoundException {
        return reviewRepository.findById(id)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ReviewNotFoundException("Product not found with id: " + id));
    }

    public List<Review> getReviewsByProductId(Long productId) {
        return reviewRepository.findByProductId(productId);

    }




}


StockControlApplication:
package gerry.stockcontrol;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class StockControlApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(StockControlApplication.class, args);
    }
}


I've made sure the folder structure is correct re. main.   I've pretty much just did for Review exactly as I did for Product so was expecting to be able to call http://localhost:8080/api/reviews and get back all Reviews like I did for Products.

Please check the application log for any exception or error. Add the relevant part to the question.

For starters your Review needs a no-args constructor, this is a JPA requirement.

Tried to replicate this but it's working fine. Please add application log for more details
